# How to return a value retrieved inside a callback function's void overriden method?

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, callback

I have the following function, which returns a long value. However, that long value (`result.id.longValue()`) is retrieved inside a callback's void overridden method, so I can't just return the retrieved value in the overridden function (as I am doing below). I am confused as to where to go from here so if anybody can provide a solution or direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
public long functionName() {
    try {
      valueSystem
          .setResultCallback(
              new CustomCallback<CustomObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(CustomObject result) {
                  return result.id.longValue();
                }
              });
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Interface of `CustomCallback`:

```
public interface MailboxCallback<T> {
  public void onCompletion(T result);
}
```

Comment: What framework?  `android.webkit.ValueCallback<T>` doesn't seem to have an `onCompletion` method.  If you want help you'll need to provide more details, preferably a [mcve].

Comment: @JimGarrison It is a custom callback (```CustomCallback```). I have attached the interface in the description.

Comment: This doesn't seem like correct usage of async, there is no point in having async calls if you also want to wait for it to return. You should instead react to events inside the async method. If you do want to do this for whatever reason, then there are several options, but one way might be to use a while loop or similar to stall the thread, and once `onCompletion` is triggered store the result as a class variable that is checked by the while loop, then the loop can exit and return the stored class variable.

Comment: @sorifiend Is a while loop continuously checking on whether ```onCompletion``` has finished the only solution?

Comment: No, there are many ways to do this. A better solution would be to not use async calls to begin with, or if you want to use async then you'll need to adjust your code logic to be event-based (maybe use job queues) rather than needing to wait on specific methods to return. It all depends on what you are trying to achieve with your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CompletableFuture` and complete it from the call back with the supplied value:

```
var future = new CompletableFuture<>();

valueSystem.setResultCallback(
    new CustomCallback<>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(CustomObject result) {
            future.complete(result.id.longValue());
        }
    });
```

From there use any of the `CompletableFuture` chaining methods to proceed dealing with the result.